# Is it a good question to ask what the geodesics of a black hole are?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, geodesics

I'm not asking the geodesics in a black hole background. I'm asking the geodesic of a black hole itself as a object. If so, how do I calculate the length of this geodesic?

Comment: What do you mean the "geodesic of a black hole as an object"? What is the *object* (note that e.g. in the Schwarzschild case the singularity is *not* usually part of the manifold)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind What about for a massive particle which will deform the spacetime?

Comment: Do you mean the trajectory accounting for [back-reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-reaction)?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to pose the massive particle as a stress energy tensor and calculate the metric from the Einstein Field Equations. But if you consider it a spherically symmetric point particle it's easy: transform coordinates to where particle is at rest and the answer, if you can consider the particle as being spherically symmetric, with no other field (no charge, no color, no weak charge, etc), it's a spherically symmetric Schwarzschild solution, for the spacetime outside the particle.

Now if you want do an inverse coordinate transformation to that solution and you have it. It'll be a Schwarzschild solution see in an accelerated or arbitrary reference frame. I've see those solutions around, you may be able to find it. I don't have the answer at my fingertips.